# Clearscript V8: how to tell if 32 or 64 bit V8 engine was used?

Tags: v8, clearscript

I have an issue where certain clients report bugs from code called from js.

One they I want to check is if this maybe is because of 32 vs 64 bit engine. How can I tell which was used? Is that something I can ask clearscript, or can I access that in js?

How is decided which engine is used, Windows bit width?

Comment: The version of V8 used depends on the device architecture--All that is needed is to check the OS and CPU architecture (ARM, x86, x64, etc...) to see which version of V8 is used. This has to be done on the C# end, however, unless you give the JS environment access to such information.

Comment: Are you sure it can't be caused by being hosted in a 32 bit process maybe? Are there any 32bit computers anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.processarchitecture?view=net-6.0) is used to determine the version of V8 in use. Additionally, [`IsOSPlatform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.isosplatform?view=net-6.0) is used to determine the OS-specific version of V8 that should be used. [Here is a list of all the options](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript/blob/master/ClearScript/V8/SplitProxy/V8SplitProxyNative.tt) which ClearScript will select from.

Comment: Indeed thx https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript/blob/master/ClearScript/V8/V8Proxy.cs